# HDFS remove all folders except one

Tags: hdfs

The standard command to remove a folder in HDFS is like this:

```
hadoop fs -rmdir -r /data/11.19
```

The linux command to remove a folder except 2 folder names is like this:

```
rm -r -v !("/data/11.19"|"/data/10.19")
```

Is there a way to remove all folder except 2 with given names? I could not find any help about that.

What I get is this error:

> 2/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

For the functional aspect, I want to keep only 2 folders. Current and last months. The format is "%m%y"
So if the current month is "11.19", I want to remove all folders except folder "11.19" and "10.19".

Answer (score 0):

Do now get confused with linus and hadoop. Linux command does not work in hadoop.
Hadoop have different set of commands.

You can move the required folders at other location in hadoop and delete the remaining ones and move them back

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /doNotDelete
hadoop fs -mv /data/11.19 /doNotDelete/
hadoop fs -mv /data/10.19 /doNotDelete/
```

Now delete all the remaining ones

```
hadoop fs -rm /data/*
```

Now put those two files back

```
hadoop fs -cp /doNotDelete/* /data/
```

Comment: Sure Hadoop commands are not Linux commands. But they are truely inspired by Linux. This is why i'm asking if there is a similar mechanic.
Thank you for your answer, not quite the way I wanted to do, but guess it will do the work for now.